# Image property acting differently on Firefox on a hover state

Tags: html, css, hover

This was originally created by Brad on his YouTube channel and I followed along with different photos as well as inserting the media queries.

[Tutorial Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qOe8lBAChE)

My question is when I hover each div (img), it works fine on Chrome and Safari. However, the image shows the whole image on Firefox. I am curious what property is causing this behaviour.

Thank you.

```css
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    background:#eee;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:'Roboto',sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    font-size:45px;
    font-weight:300;
    margin:10px;
    z-index:1;
}

h2 span {
    font-size:30px;
}

p {
    font-size:20px;
    z-index:1;
}

.container {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
    grid-gap:10px;
}

.container > div {
    cursor:pointer;
    height:300px;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;

    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: center;
    justify-content: center;;
    align-items:center;

    transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
} 

.container > div:hover {
    opacity:0.85;
    transform:scale(0.98);
}

.container > div:nth-of-type(1) {
    grid-column:1 / 3;
}

.container > div:nth-child(6) {
    grid-column:3 / 5;
}

.container > div:nth-child(9) {
    grid-column:3 / 5;
}

.container > div:nth-child(10) {
    grid-column:1 / 3;
}
 
.bg1 {
    background:url('https://i.ibb.co/7WYNNFR/onepiece.jpg');    
    position: relative;
}


.bg1::before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:0;
}

.bg2 {
    background:url('https://i.ibb.co/nMWtjrM/boruto.jpg');
    position: relative;
}

.bg2::before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px){

    .container > div:nth-of-type(1) {
        grid-column:1 / 5;
    }

    .container > div:nth-of-type(2) {
        grid-column:1 / 3;
    }


    .container > div:nth-of-type(3) {
        grid-column:3 / 5;
    }

    .container > div:nth-of-type(4) {
        grid-column:1 / 3;
    }

    .container > div:nth-of-type(5) {
        grid-column:3 / 5;
    }
    
    .container > div:nth-child(6) {
        grid-column:1 / 5;
    }

    .container > div:nth-child(7) {
        grid-column:1 / 3;
    }
    
    .container > div:nth-child(8) {
        grid-column:3 / 5;
    }
    
    .container > div:nth-child(9) {
        grid-column:1 / 3;
    }
    
    .container > div:nth-child(10) {
        grid-column:3 / 5;
    }

    .container > div:nth-child(11) {
        grid-column:1 / 3;
    }

    .container > div:nth-child(12) {
        grid-column:3 / 5;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Health Panel</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bg1">
            <h2>16 <span>| 24</span></h2>
            <p>Goals Completed</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bg1">
            <h2><i class="fas fa-battery-three-quarters"></i></h2>
            <p>Respiration</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg2">
            <h2><i class="fas fa-running"></i></h2>
            <p>Miles</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg1">
            <h2>36 &deg;</h2>
            <p>Temperature</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg1">
            <h2><i class="fas fa-bed"></i></h2>
            <p>Sleep Keep</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg2">
            <h2>98 <span>bpm</span></h2>
            <p>Heart Rate</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg1">
            <h2>170 <span>lbs</span></h2>
            <p>Weight</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg1">
            <h2>28 <span>%</span></h2>
            <p>Fat Percentage</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg2">
            <h2>118 <span>mgdl</span></h2>
            <p>Blood Glucose</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg2">
            <h2>680 <span>kcal</span></h2>
            <p>AVG Consumption</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg2">
            <h2><i class="fas fa-dumbbell"></i></h2>
            <p>Workouts</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bg2">
            <h2>85 <span>%</span></h2>
            <p>Body Hydration</p>
          </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is changed?

Comment: Sorry for not elaborating the problem. So on Chrome and Safari, images on each section stays the same because of the image attachment property being fixed. However, the image shows the whole image on Firefox. I hope this is not just my computer?